# Returning Kth smallest element in a BST

Tags: c++

I wrote the following code snippet to return the `K`th smallest element in a BST:

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * struct TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode *left;
 *     TreeNode *right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
 * };
 */

class Solution {
public:

    int kthSmallest(TreeNode* root, int k) {
        if(root==NULL)
            return -2;
        cout<<"Root value "<<root->val<<" and k value "<<k<<"\n";

        kthSmallest(root->left, k-1);
        if((k)==0)
            return root->val;
        kthSmallest(root->right, k-1);
    }
};
```

I basically just do an inorder traversal of the tree and decrement the value of `k` during each recursive call.  So, in this way, when the value of `k` equals `0`, I have found the node and just return it.

Following is the output of my debugging statements:

> Root value 1 and k value 3 
>   Root value 2 and k value 2 
>   Root value 4 and k value 1
>   Root value 8 and k value 0
>   Root value 9 and k value 0
>   Root value 5 and k value 1
>   Root value 10 and k value 0
>   Root value 11 and k value 0
>   Root value 3 and k value 2
>   Root value 6 and k value 1
>   Root value 12 and k value 0
>   Root value 7 and k value 1

I am unable to understand why the program keeps on executing even after `k` has become `0`.  What have I missed?  I appreciate your help.

**Edit**:  I don't think the question description is required, but if needed, it can be found here: [LeetCode: Find Kth smallest element in a BST](https://leetcode.com/problems/kth-smallest-element-in-a-bst/#/description).  Also, please note that I cannot edit the function prototype.  Also, the question says that the `k` would be a valid number between `1` and BST's total number of elements.

Comment: What are you doing with the value that the recursive calls to `kthSmallest` returns?

Comment: If the value of `k` used during that recursive call was not `0`, then I just ignore it.

Comment: Then why bother returning anything to begin with, if you just ignore it?

Comment: As for your problem, you return from the recursive calls when `k == 0`, but in the calling function `k != 0`. Please learn how to use a debugger to step through your code line by line, stepping into the recursive calls. That should make it much clearer what happens.

Comment: Could you kindly elaborate?  I am returning a value because my overall function should return the `K`th smallest element.  Ideally, I wish the value is returned only when `k==0`.

Comment: What if root is not null and `k != 0`? What does the function return?

Comment: @0x499602D2, edited the question.  Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Without much thinking about this, but a routine that is declared `int`  need to return an `int`. And yours does not. The last statement should likely be  `return kthSmallest(root->right, k-1);`

Answer (score 0):

Variables are not shared between (recursive or not) calls. Each call will have `k` being a normal local variable whose value is promptly forgotten once the function returns.

If you have `k == 1` and then do `kthSmallest(root->left, k-1)` it's only in the recursive call that `k == 0`. In the callee the value of `k` is *still* `1`.

This algorithm will never work as coded, because you rely on arguments and local variables being shared.

You also don't propagate the K:th smallest value from the bottom of the call tree. You just throw it away, and in the end (the very first call to `kthSmallest`) don't return *anything* which leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Could you kindly set me in the right direction by pointing how I could correct my code?  Kindly do not provide me the code; please just give me pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You code would not work as is, as in the previous comment.
You could do something along the lines of:

```
int kthSmallest(TreeNode* root, int k) {
    int i = 0;
    return kthSmallest(root, &i, k);
}

int kthSmallest(TreeNode* root, int *i, int k) {
    if(root == nullptr)
        return INT32_MAX;

    int left = kthSmallest(root->left, i, k);

    if (left != INT32_MAX)
        return left;

    if (++*i == k)
        return root->val;

    kthSmallest(root->right, i, k);
}
```